# How i get subView using a Rect in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, cgrect

There is a Main View with subview. I need to get these subviews.

For example, I created a view:

[image]

With the Swift Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Check if has view in rect area

        let rect1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        if CGRectContainsPoint(rect1, rect1.origin) { // return true

            print("TRUE")

        } else {

            print("FALSE")

        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the view you are "touching" the Rect in size or origin.

In the above example, I created three subviews with different colors between them.

**I need to get the view and make a print() with the backgroundColor.**

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This func fix the problem:

```
func intersectingViewWithView(panView: UIView) -> UIView? {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view != panView {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(panView.frame, view.frame) {
                return view
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```